# Ruby: build hash by mapping arrays to an array

Tags: arrays, json, ruby, hash

I have a **dates** array containing 31 items (shortened here for clarity)

```
Tuesday 8, November
Wednesday 9, November
#etc.
```

and a **movies** hash containing 31 items, each containing movie names and showtimes (shortened here for clarity)

```
{:movie=>"The Neon Demon", :time=>"4:15 PM"}
{:movie=>"Breaking a Monster", :time=>"6:45 PM"}
{:movie=>"The Citizen", :time=>"9:00 PM"}
```

I am trying to build a hash for json output which has this structure

```
[
  {
    "Tuesday 8, November": {
      "movies": [
        {
          "movie": "The Neon Demon",
          "time": "4:15 PM"
        },
        {
          "movie": "Breaking a Monster",
          "time": "6:45 PM"
        },
        {
          "movie": "The Citizen",
          "time": "9:00 PM"
        }
      ]
  },
  {
    "Wednesday 9, November": {
      "movies": [
        {
          "movie": "The First Monday in May",
          "time": "4:15 PM"
        },
        {
          "movie": "The Neon Demon",
          "time": "6:30 PM"
        },
        {
          "movie": "Breaking a Monster",
          "time": "9:00 PM"
        }
      ]
    }, #etc
  }
]
```

Right now I'm using

```
Output = []
Output << { dates => { movies: movies }}
puts JSON.pretty_generate Output
```

But its not arranging elements correctly and I can't figure out the best way to do it. Can anyone give me a tip on how to do it correctly? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're really just one call to [`zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-zip) away from a solution:

```
movies = [
  {:movie=>"The Neon Demon", :time=>"4:15 PM"},
  {:movie=>"Breaking a Monster", :time=>"6:45 PM"},
  {:movie=>"The Citizen", :time=>"9:00 PM"}
]

dates = [
  'Tuesday 8, November',
  'Wednesday 9, November',
  'Thursday 10, November'
]

dates.zip(movies).to_h
# => {"Tuesday 8, November"=>{:movie=>"The Neon Demon", :time=>"4:15 PM"}, ... }
```

As a note date formats like that are extremely annoying from a programming perspective since they can't be sorted and are language specific. ISO date format like `2016-11-08` works a lot better in practice.

Comment: To add on to the point about formatting, you can also use `l` to format the ISO date to look like your locale's time format.

Comment: Thanks. zip looks very convenient. I will try it and get back to you.

Comment: This is super-simple and certainly works but the output is not as I expected. There should be more than one movie per date, however, I obviously didn't make this clear in my question, so I'm marking this as a solution anyway. Thanks! 

Thanks also @Eli Sadoff for the point about date formatting.

Comment: `dates.map { |d| [ d, movies ] }.to_h` does it that way, but keep in mind they all share the same movies list. If you need to make individual modifications be sure to `.dup` the array: `movies.dup`.

Answer (score 1):

There is rarely just one way to do a calculation in Ruby, and this is no exception. Here's another way. Note that I've allowed for the possibility that two or more movies are showing on the same day.

**Code**

```
def aggregate_by_date(dates, movies)
  movies.each_index.with_object({}) { |i,h| (h[dates[i]] ||= []) << movies[i] }
end
```

**Example**

```
movies = [
  {:movie=>"The Neon Demon", :time=>"4:15 PM"},
  {:movie=>"Breaking a Monster", :time=>"6:45 PM"},
  {:movie=>"The Citizen", :time=>"9:00 PM"},
  {:movie=>"Citizen Kane", :time=>"9:40 PM"}
]

dates = [
  'Tuesday 8, November',
  'Wednesday 9, November',
  'Thursday 10, November',
  'Wednesday 9, November'
]

h = aggregate_by_date(dates, movies)
  #=> {"Tuesday 8, November"=>[{:movie=>"The Neon Demon", :time=>"4:15 PM"}],
  #    "Wednesday 9, November"=>[{:movie=>"Breaking a Monster", :time=>"6:45 PM"},
  #                              {:movie=>"Citizen Kane", :time=>"9:40 PM"}],
  #    "Thursday 10, November"=>[{:movie=>"The Citizen", :time=>"9:00 PM"}]}
```

**Explanation**

For `i = 0` we compute:

```
(h[dates[i]] ||= []) << movies[i]
  #=> (h[dates[i] = h[dates[i] || []) <<  movies[i]
  #=> (h[dates[i] = nil || []) <<  movies[i]
  #=> (h[dates[i] = []) <<  movies[i]
  #=> h["Tuesday 8, November"]=>[{:movie=>"The Neon Demon", :time=>"4:15 PM"}]

h #=>  {"Tuesday 8, November"=>[{:movie=>"The Neon Demon", :time=>"4:15 PM"}]}
```

For `i = 1` the calculation is similar:

```
(h[dates[i]] ||= []) << movies[i]
  #=> "Wednesday 9, November"=>[{:movie=>"Breaking a Monster", :time=>"6:45 PM"}] 
h #=> {"Tuesday 8, November"=>[{:movie=>"The Neon Demon", :time=>"4:15 PM"}],
#      "Wednesday 9, November"=>[{:movie=>"Breaking a Monster", :time=>"6:45 PM"}]}
```

For `i = 2`, once more, the calculation is similar:

```
(h[dates[i]] ||= []) << movies[i]
  #=> "Thursday 10, November"=>[{:movie=>"The Citizen", :time=>"9:00 PM"}]
h #=> {"Tuesday 8, November"=>[{:movie=>"The Neon Demon", :time=>"4:15 PM"}],
  #    "Wednesday 9, November"=>[{:movie=>"Breaking a Monster", :time=>"6:45 PM"}],
  #    "Thursday 10, November"=>[{:movie=>"The Citizen", :time=>"9:00 PM"}]}
```

But for `i = 3`, things change, as `h` now has a key `'Wednesday 9, November'`, so the calculation is simpler:

```
(h[dates[i]] ||= []) << movies[i]
  #=> (h[dates[i] = h[dates[i] || []) <<  movies[i]
  #=> (h[dates[i] =
  #     [{:movie=>"Breaking a Monster", :time=>"6:45 PM"}] || []) <<  movies[i]
  #=> h[dates[i] =
        [{:movie=>"Breaking a Monster", :time=>"6:45 PM"}] <<  movies[i]
  #=> h['Wednesday 9, November'] =
  #=>   [{:movie=>"Breaking a Monster", :time=>"6:45 PM"},
  #      {:movie=>"Citizen Kane", :time=>"9:40 PM"}]
```

`h`, which is now returned from the block, equals the hash produced in the example.

**Alternative method**

Here is another way this could be written, which I present without explanation.

```
def aggregate_by_date(dates, movies)
  dates.zip(movies).group_by(&:first).
    tap { |h| h.keys.each { |k| h[k] = h[k].map(&:last) } }
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you explain a little bit what is happening here. I get the gist but, for example, with_object.({}) is totally lost on me!

Comment: Using [Enumerator#with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object) (the object being an initially-empty hash, referenced by the block variable `h`, which is returned by the block) is just a way of writing the following in one line rather than three: `h = {};  movies.each_index { |i| h[dates[i]] = movies[i] }; h`. See also [Array#each_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-each_index). Any other questions?

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are good.  Here is a solution that will give the output you expected.

```
movies = [
  {:movie=>"The Neon Demon", :time=>"4:15 PM"},
  {:movie=>"Breaking a Monster", :time=>"6:45 PM"},
  {:movie=>"The Citizen", :time=>"9:00 PM"}
]

dates = [
  'Tuesday 8, November',
  'Tuesday 8, November',
  'Thursday 10, November'
]

# Add date to movies array so that we can do group_by in next step
movies_array_with_date = movies.each.with_index{ |m, i| m[:date] = dates[i] }

# Group by the array elements by date
movies_grouped_by_date = movies_array_with_date.group_by {|e| e[:date]}

# Now get rid of date from values of hash as it is not desired in final output
desired_hash = movies_grouped_by_date.each {|k,v| v.each {|a| a.delete(:date)}}

#=> {"Tuesday 8, November"=>
#       [{:movie=>"The Neon Demon", :time=>"4:15 PM"},
#        {:movie=>"Breaking a Monster", :time=>"6:45 PM"}],
#    "Thursday 10, November"=>
#       [{:movie=>"The Citizen", :time=>"9:00 PM"}]}


desired_hash = movies_grouped_by_date.each {|k,v| v.each {|a| a.delete(:date)}}

puts JSON.pretty_generate desired_hash

#=> {
#      "Tuesday 8, November": [
#          {
#            "movie": "The Neon Demon",
#            "time": "4:15 PM"
#          },
#          {
#            "movie": "Breaking a Monster",
#            "time": "6:45 PM"
#          }
#        ],
#        "Thursday 10, November": [
#          {
#            "movie": "The Citizen",
#            "time": "9:00 PM"
#          }
#        ]
#      }
```